# Out of Memory Error Nexus 7 android 4.2.1

Tags: android, memory, out-of-memory, nexus-7

I am developing an app for all android devices. It is working good on all device and I tested it on Samsung Galaxy S1, Galaxy Nexus, Motorola Xoom, HTC One and also on Amazon Kindle Fire.
It runs perfectly on all devices but when i tried using it on Nexus 7, it crashes and in log it says Out of Memory Error. I tried using `System.gc();` in Activity#onPause() method but in vain. There are alternative drawables and layouts exist in app.
Please help me to resolve this issue. This issue is only specific to Nexus 7.
Below is stacktrace:

```
    12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.app/com.android.app.activity.MyListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at com.android.app.activity.MyListActivity.onCreate(MyListActivity.java:39)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     ... 11 more
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     ... 23 more
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3328)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:431)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
12-05 16:42:45.625: E/AndroidRuntime(8759):     ... 26 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have added my question, please have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya i had faced this issue too but not found a valid solution but you can try using `android:largeHeap="true"` in manifest at application level